# Textview Gradient

Tags: android, textview

Can any one tell me how to create this type of textview ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Map view

```
  @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
    strokePaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    strokePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    strokePaint.setTextSize(16);
    strokePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    textPaint.setTextSize(16);
    textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    canvas.drawText("Some Text", 100, 100, strokePaint);
    canvas.drawText("Some Text", 100, 100, textPaint);

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}
```

This will make a stroke of 2 pixel. This may help You